# how to do recursive components in vue 3?

Tags: vuejs3

I have 2 components that I am trying to add recursion to, previously I just had to specify the name of the top component in the inner component and everything worked. Now in vue 3 it doesn't work anymore and I can't figure out how to make recursive components?

I have 2 components - team-table.vue and team-table-tr.vue.

Team-table:

```
<template lang="pug">
.team-table
  table.team-table__team-table
    thead
      tr
        th {{  $t('team.line') }}
        th {{  $t('team.user') }}
        th {{ $t('team.in_team')}}
        th E/M/H/G
        th {{ $t('team.real_estate')}}
        th Turbo/Fast
        th {{ $t('team.info') }}
    team-table-tr(v-for="(item, ind) in data" :key="'ind'+ind" :data="item")

</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'team-table',
  data() {
    return {
      data: []
    }
  },
  props: {
    ids: {
      type: [String, Number]
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    if(this.ids) this.init()
  },
  methods: {
    async init() {
      this.vloading = true;
      const data = await this.$request(`/api/users/${this.ids}/team/?user_id=${this.ids}&limit=10`);
      this.vloading = false
      if(data && data.data) this.data = data.data.results
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

team-table-tr.vue

```
tbody.team-table-tr
  tr
    td {{ data.c1 }}
    td {{ data.c2 }}
    td {{ data.c3 }}
    td {{ data.c4 }}
    td {{ data.c5 }}
    td {{ data.c6 }}
    td {{ data.c7 }}
  transition(name="fade")
    tr
      td(colspan="7"  )
        team-table(v-if="data && data.id" :ids="data.id")
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "team-table-tr",
  data() {
    return {
      open: false
    }
  },
  components: {
    TeamTable: () => import("@/components/team-table/team-table.vue")
  },
  props: {
    data: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {}
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

How i can do that recursion, because logic vue2 or nuxt there is not working (

Comment: Can't run your code, so please explain what does "not working" mean?  Are there any errors, or what's the expected vs actual result you're seeing?  What debugging have you done?  Can you narrow it down to anything?